# Hide the password parameter from the Inno Setup logs

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to create a silent install with inno setup and dump a log in case setup fails.

My problem is that I want to pass a password into the setup as a parameter but not have it come out in the log file.

Is there any way to mask strings, hide parameters from log file or a best practice way to pass passwords not involving parameters?

Comment: I need this too, the question was answered here, although unsatisfactorily in my opinion. I think someone is going to have to make the change and do a pull request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629742/inno-setup-suppress-setup-command-line-log-entry

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you still need it but in case somebody else tries to mask a string, here's how I did it to mask the entered password in the installation summary:

```
StringOfChar('*', Length(Page.Values[0]))
```