# Logging of inno setup without command-line log

Tags: logging, inno-setup

I have to log the different steps of the installation of an inno setup (in \verysilent mode). But I don't want to log the command line because it contains some critical information (like password).

How can I easily keep the logging without the command-line log ?

Comment: You can execute your setup with `/LOG` parameter, or set `SetupLogging` directive to `yes`. That will create a log file.

Comment: 'Kay. But this parameter log my command line (which contains critical informations). I need to delete easily that log while keeping the other logs

Comment: I see. So you're asking for the same as [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26629742/960757) does (how to avoid `Setup command line:` log entry), don't you ? But of course I don't have anything against opening the log file, finding and deleting just that `Setup command line:` log entry. That is possible, but is that what you want ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inno Setup - suppress "Setup command line:" log entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629742/inno-setup-suppress-setup-command-line-log-entry)