# Inno Setup hide a Log entry

Tags: inno-setup

I want to be able to hide a particular entry from displaying in the Inno Setup log file (i.e. I do not want a particular command to be visible in the log file). Is there any way of selectively telling a particular command in the [Run] section not to be logged?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Perhaps write a wee utility to [run] postinstall

Comment: So as not to expose a password being passed to another executable in the [Run] section. I have logging switched off by default, but anyone could easily switch it on again using the /log switch.

Comment: This should improved, IMHO. I [`can think of another issue`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26629742/960757) about logging password passed through the setup's command line.

Comment: Yes, that would also be an issue.

Comment: That information is trivial to see anyway, even without any logging, just using built in Windows tools. You should find another way to pass the password, maybe an environment variable, or passing it via stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Logging is hardcoded in Inno Setup with no explicit way to skip certain entries at this time. You can [`read this here`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Main.pas#L3673) in the source code (notice, there's no condition nor parameter that would be passed to the [`Log`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Logging.pas#L130) function so it would be able to skip the entry to be logged later on).

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming.